# Will I need to call this pcre2_code_free() function to free up memory for a c++ class object?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, pcre

This [`pcre2_code_free()`](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2_code_free.html) needs to be called to free up memory used by a structure `pcre2_code`. I am delcaring the `pcre2_code` as a class variable like this:

```
class Pcre2Regex{
    private:
    std::string pat_str;
    std::string modifier;
    PCRE2_SPTR pattern;
    pcre2_code *code;
    ...

    public:

    Pcre2Regex(const std::string& re,const std::string& mod=""){compile(re,mod);}
    void compile(void){compile(pat_str,modifier);}
    void compile(const std::string& re,const std::string& mod="");
    pcre2_code* getPcreCode(){return code;}
    void free(void){pcre2_code_free(code);}

};
```

Then I am creating an object like this:

```
{
Pcre2Regex re=Pcre2Regex("sample pattern");

///and calling re.free() before going out of scope
}
```

Is it really necessary to call the `re.free()` method before the object goes out of scope. If I leave everything upto the default destructor will there be a memory leak?

I have tried to put that `free()` function inside a destructor, but **trying to free the memory of `code` from destructor yields a segmentation fault.**

Note:

The `pcre2_code` is a [c](/questions/tagged/c) structure which uses [c](/questions/tagged/c) memory management codes to allocate memory for its' members.  `pcre2_code_free()` frees the memory used by the structure (it's members) using pure [c](/questions/tagged/c) memory deallocation function.

This is how I am setting values to the `code`:

```
code = pcre2_compile(
    pattern,                    /* the pattern */
    PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED,  /* indicates pattern is zero-terminated */
    compile_opts,                      /* default options */
    &error_number,          /* for error number */
    &error_offset,          /* for error offset */
    NULL);                  /* use default compile context */
```

The above function is being called by the class member function `compile()` i.e it is being called as soon as the class object being created.
All the memory allocation tasks are handled by the [`pcre2` library](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/index.html) function [`pcre2_compile()`](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2_compile.html). (`pcre2_compile()` as well as other pcre2 related variables and functions are defined in a static library (pcre2-8.a).

Comment: Do you have anything that sets `code`? If so please show it. Currently the code shown does not initialize `code` to any value.

Comment: @TheDark added part of the code that initializes the `code` struct variable.

Comment: I'd suggest putting some trace writes in the code that calls `pcre2_compile` and `pcre2_code_free`. Check that the compile and free calls match. As you have a raw pointer in your class, but no copy constructor or assignment operator, it is possible that you are making an inadvertent copy of an object, which is causing you to have two objects with the same `code` pointer. This would cause multiple free's with the same value and could cause the issue you are seeing.

Comment: Yes, you *do* need to call `pcre2_code_free`, preferably in the destructor for RAII. Implement the [rule of three/five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), as The Dark suggests.